# Reset VR camera orentation three.js

Tags: three.js, webvr

I want to reset the camera orientation to it initial orientation on entering VR or by clicking a button using three.js. In OrbitControls there is a function to reset camera orientaion and position to initial state.I want to do something just like it.

```
orbitcontrols.reset();
```

In previous three.js version there was a function to reset VR camera orientaion.

```
controls.resetPose();
```

But this function is not available now.

Can anybody please help me with how to reset VR camera orientaion and position to initial state?